# Capture ID from a link click and pass it into a popup form

Tags: javascript, forms, parameter-passing

I have three links that all have the same class but different ID's.  When a link with the classname is clicked, the user sees a popup form.  What I am attempting to do is capture the individual ID from the click and pass it into the form as a hidden field.

```
<div id="IA"><a class="addProdClick">Get a Quote</a></div>
<div id="MP"><a class="addProdClick">Get a Quote</a></div>
<div id="GS"><a class="addProdClick">Get a Quote</a></div>
```

I want to be able to add the value to the following hidden field in the popup form once captured:

```
/*======== This is the popup form which is show to the user when they click the "Get a Quote." ========*/
<form id="addProdGateway" action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" id="product" name="product" value="">
</form>
```

Depending on what the ID is on the form, the user will be redirected to the correct site.  I have the latter half of the js already built out, but cannot seem to figure out how to capture that ID and pass it into the form before the submission.

I already have the validation and processing built out below:

```
jQuery(document).on('submit','#addProdGateway',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    validationAddProdGateway();

    /*======== AJAX to submit a Pardot Form Handler ========*/
}

function validationAddProdGateway()
{
    var x = 0;
    var theForm = document.forms["addProdGateway"];
    var email = theForm.elements["email"].value;
    var source = theForm.elements["source"].value;
    var product = theForm.elements["product"].value;
    var url;

    if (product = "IA")
    {
        url = "https://www.ia.com"
    }
    else if (product = "MP")
    {
        url = "https://www.mp.com"
    }
    else if (product = "GS")
    {
        url = "https://www.gs.com"
    }

    /*======== Form Validation ========*/

    window.location.href = url;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The snippet below shows how to get the clicked element's parent ID using jQuery:

```js
$('.addProdClick').click(function(el) {
  $('#product').val($(this).parent().attr('id'));  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="IA"><a class="addProdClick">Get a Quote</a></div>
<div id="MP"><a class="addProdClick">Get a Quote</a></div>
<div id="GS"><a class="addProdClick">Get a Quote</a></div>

<input type="hidden" readonly="readonly" id="product" name="product" value="">
```

Comment: Once it's in the console log, how can I pull it into the popup form's hidden field?

Comment: I have tried a similar code snippet, but was unsuccessful.  The problem I cannot figure out is how to store the id in the hidden form field.  Getting it is not an issue, I'm just not sure how to process afterwards.

Comment: If you inspect the snippet above with your dev tools, you should see how the value of the hidden input field changes when you click any of the links. If you have trouble getting this to work in your own setup, maybe you could share a reproduction of your issue in a fiddle or similar?

Comment: The issue I'm mainly combating is that the form and, therefore, the hidden field is not present on the screen when the user clicks the button.  The button activates the popup form, so essentially, the above code is attempting to assign a value to an ID it cannot find, then the form with the ID pops up.

Comment: I see. Can you add the code that is responsible for opening the popup to your question? Maybe you can pass the selected ID down and fill it in the hidden input after your form has been created.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a WordPress Plugin (Popups 1.7.0.1 - Premium v1.8.0.1 by TimerSys) that generates the popup.

Comment: Right, that complicates things. An incredibly hacky and ugly way to work around this might be wrapping the call that inserts the ID in the hidden input in a timeout... (I have no experience with wordpress)